# Issue with libsqlite3 - Xcode6 Beta5

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

```
Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

is there, but

```
Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

is NOT there.

Any alternative for this? Is this intentional or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Just re-installed Xcode and it is there. works now